# Class 'SimplePasswordHasher' not found

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to use the authentication cakephp provides but I'm having issues with the resources.

I have SimplePasswordHasher.php saved in controller/component.  While using the call

```
App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
```

And then later calling

```
$passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
```

It can't find the class. If I alter the App::uses to not have "/Auth" at the end it finds the class but promptly fails when SimplePasswordHasher tries to call

```
App::uses('AbstractPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
```

Any ideas of what I might be missing in my directories or my set up? I've researched other issues like this but it usually ends in the App::uses being altered to what I have it as.

Comment: Upgrade to CakePHP 2.4+.

Comment: Ok, That seems to do the trick. Thanks, guess it wasn't I necessarily did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting that because the class SimplePasswordHasher.php is not there in the cakePhp package. I had a similar problem. Uprading to 2.4 can work. As for me. I coped the class and placed it inside Auth foler(\lib\Cake\Controller\Component\Auth) and i was sorted.

Answer (score 0):

in `app/Model/User.php` change to:

```
App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
```